# Unable to restart rogue Jenkins on Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, jenkins

I was configuring Jenkins last night to run some reporting plugins (codestyle, findbugs, cobertura). When I ran my build job it got hung up somewhere in codestyle, and the server ui became unresponsive.

Today I logged in to the server and the Jenkins log is reporting errors that look like the server ran out of memory, but more than that, I cannot seem to stop or restart the server. I have limited experience with services in linux.

Jenkins was installed on Ubuntu with atp. I have tried `$ sudo /etc/init.d/jenkins restart` but it reports

```
* Starting Jenkins Continuous Integration Server jenkins                                                                           
The selected http port (8080) seems to be in use by another program
Please select another port to use for jenkins
```

When I try to run `service jenkins status` to get a pid to kill i get

```
2 instances of jenkins are running at the moment
but the pidfile /var/run/jenkins/jenkins.pid is missing
```

Running `netstat` and `ps` has identified the port being held by a jenkins instance.

How can I recover from this?

Comment: Have you tried finding the process id for example via jps and then call kill on the process id?

Comment: This box was installed and configured by someone that doesn't work here anymore, and for whatever reason it has a JDK 7 installed (somehow) but not jps, javap, or any other useful utilities. Ubuntu apt claims that an OpenJDK 6 is installed but javac -version says java 7 so I'm not even sure what to add/update/delete/etc.

Comment: You might want to take a look at the update-alternatives system for the configuration of java. Otherwise look for jenkins in the process list and get the process id that way.

Answer (score 4):

Mostly I was concerned about abruptly killing the Jenkins server while it has gone rogue. Something this tied into process with server connections and plugins makes me wary of taking a shotgun to the process.

That's exactly what I did. `server jenkins status` didn't work, so I got the process id from `netstat -tulpn`. `kill -15` didn't work so I did `kill -9`, waited a respectful grieving period, then restarted the Jenkins service.

I will next be investigating the root problem of running out of memory in my Jenkins installation so hopefully this doesn't happen again while I am firewalled away from my server.

Answer (score 0):

Where is your server hosted? 
I had the same issue with AWS EC2 server.

Command lines did not work to reboot the server.
However, on AWS admin console, I did: EC2 -> restart and it works like a charm.

This may not be a solution but a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do

```
sudo ps aux | grep jenkins
```

To find a list of jenkins processes. Then I ran

```
sudo kill <pid>
```

And then finally

```
sudo service jenkins restart
```